# Cocoapods install build error

Tags: ruby, xcode, rubygems, cocoapods

I'm trying to install cocoapods on my mac and I get the following error:

```
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing cocoapods:
    ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

    /Users/aleix/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p247/bin/ruby extconf.rb
creating Makefile

make "DESTDIR="
compiling generator.c
make: I.: No such file or directory
make: [generator.o] Error 1 (ignored)
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
make: dynamic: No such file or directory
make: [generator.bundle] Error 1 (ignored)

make "DESTDIR=" install
compiling generator.c
make: I.: No such file or directory
make: [generator.o] Error 1 (ignored)
linking shared-object json/ext/generator.bundle
make: dynamic: No such file or directory
make: [generator.bundle] Error 1 (ignored)
./install -m 0755 generator.bundle ./.gem.20130930-1849-csgswk/json/ext
make: ./install: No such file or directory
make: *** [install-so] Error 1
```

I've search around and I cannot find any answer.

[Update]
Looking at the generation Makefile, CC variable is blank

```
CC =
CXX = clang++
LIBRUBY = $(LIBRUBY_A)
LIBRUBY_A = lib$(RUBY_SO_NAME)-static.a
LIBRUBYARG_SHARED =
LIBRUBYARG_STATIC = -l$(RUBY_SO_NAME)-static
empty =
OUTFLAG = -o $(empty)
COUTFLAG = -o $(empty(
```

It's really strange!!

Comment: I've more information, I've looked at the configure Makefile and the CC variable is blank.

Answer (score 0):

Did you install Comand Line Tools for XCode (XCode -> Preferences -> Downloads -> Components tab -> Comand Line Tools -> Install)?